# How many thread group can be executed at a time during performance test?

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I've executed 15 Thread group at time during performance test, but some of thread group didn't executed. Is there any limitation about number of thread group for test execution? Or how many number of active thread group can be executed at a time?

Comment: It should work, maybe you have error/duration limit that stop executing ?

Comment: When I executed every thread group only keeping active one thread group and all thread group were working

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the limit of [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) is as high as [32-bit Integer maximum value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647).

So you should not be experiencing problems with 15 Thread Groups given you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) in particular:

1. Run your test in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Disable all the [listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test run
3. Limit test elements to the absolute minimum, each pre/post processor or assertion has its cost so make sure that your test is as efficient as possible
4. JMeter default configuration is suitable for tests development and debugging, you will need to perform tuning if you plan to run a load test, i.e. at least increase JVM size

If you still experience problems:

- check [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file for any suspicious entries
- consider running your test in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) (remember to proportionally decrease the number of threads as JMeter engines are independent and if you have 100 threads defined in the Test Plan and 3 remote engines - you will deliver 100 * 3 = 300 virtual users)